# Ordering of Asynchronous method calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadpool

I am working on a class library that logs audit details of a web application in several types of datasources(file, xml, database) based on policies defined in the web configuration file.

My Audit log method has a signature similar to this:
public static void LogInfo(User user, Module module, List lst);

Web application uses this method to log important pieces of details like warnings, error and even exception details.

Since in a single workflow, there are more than 700+ calls to these methods , I thought of making them asynchronous. I used simple method from ***ThreadPool*** class called ***QueueUserWorkItem***

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => LogInfo(User user, Module module, List<Object> lst) );
```

but this does not ensure the order in which work item was queued to it. Even though all my information was logged but entire ordering was messed up. In my text file my logs were not in the order in which they were called.

Is there a way I can control the ordering of the threads being called using QueueUserWorkItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can specify ordering when using `QueueUserWorkItem`.

To run the logging in parallel (on some background thread), you could use `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. This is a thread-safe collection that can be accessed from multiple threads. You could create one work item (or a thread) that reads elements from the collection and writes them to a file. Your main application would add items to the collection. The fact that you're adding items to the collection from a single thread should guarantee that they will be read in the right order.

To keep things simple, you can store `Action` values in the queue:

```
ConcurrentQueue<Action> logOperations = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

// To add logging operation from main thread:
logOperations.Add(() => LogInfo(user, module, lst));
```

The background task can just take `Action`s from the queue and run them:

```
// Start this when you create the `logOperations` collection
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => {
    Action op;
    // Repeatedly take log operations & run them
    while (logOperations.TryDequeue(out op)) op();
});
```

If you need to stop the background processor (that writes data to the log), you can create a `CancellationTokenSource` and also end the `while` loop when the token is being cancelled (by the main thread). This cha be checked using `IsCancellationRequested` property ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested.aspx))

Comment: **EDIT** I originally suggested using `BlockingCollection`, but using `ConcurrentQueue` is good enough in this case. (Actually, I even realized this before seeing Brizio's answer :-))

Comment: I will be calling Audit method multiple times from life cycle events of page. In fact it can be called multiple times from a single method too. Can ConcurrentQueue<T> take care of this ?

Comment: @Kunal: Yes, you can add multiple actions (by calling `Add` repeatedly).

Comment: You should reconsider `BlockingCollection`. `ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue` is going to return `false` the first time the queue goes empty, which will cause your thread to exit. You can write the logic to wait for items, etc., or you can just use `BlockingCollection`. `ConcurrentQueue.TryDequeue` does not support cancellation. You'll need `BlockingCollection` for that.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, I think you're right - using `BlockingCollection` was probably a better idea! (you don't need blocking on the producer side, but the cancellation is quite useful thing to have).

Comment: @Tomas: Sorry got out of it for sometime, Thanks for putting your suggestion. I am still facing some issue in implementing this solution in Asp.net. Problem is.. When and where I should start my background thread ?. I could have easily managed this in win forms but in web(ASP.NET) there are concepts of postback and page life cycle events. I assume I can't start the background thread in a page event say page_Load(), Grid_Bind(), button_Clicks(). My logging utility is to be used as class library and web application will call its logging function in each of its event.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this would be to put your data in a queue, and then having a single task picking from that queue and writing them in order. If you are using .net 4.0 You could use [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), which is thread safe, otherwise a simple Queue with proper locks would work as well.

The thread consuming the queue could then periodically check for any element inside the queue, and for each one of them it could log. This way the lengthy operation (logging) could be in its own thread, whereas in the main thread you do simply adds.